# INNER JOIN should happen only when a condition is fulfilled

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, inner-join

I am trying to "short-circuit" an INNER JOIN, if condition isn't met.

**What I tried:**
I found that if a Left Join is preceded with a False clause on "ON" condition, the LEFT JOIN fails. Hence, I tried to simulate INNER JOIN with LEFT OUTER JOIN and WHERE clause got the execution plan as below:

```
DECLARE @a nvarchar(4) = 'All'

SELECT A.*
FROM [dbo].[your_table] A
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[your_table_2] B
     ON @a <> 'All'
WHERE A.City_Code = CASE WHEN @a <> 'All' 
                    THEN B.City_Code 
                    ELSE A.City_Code END
```

This will "short-circuit" the left join and it will never occur. Execution plan is below:

[image]

But then when I tried to execute the same statement by declaring the variable as 'Al' and not 'All', I saw execution plan was still the same.

[image]

I am puzzled if Join happened in the initial step or not?

**What I want:** 
I want to know whether the above approach is correct? Is it really short-circuiting the INNER JOIN? 
I basically want the INNER JOIN to happen between the two tables only when variable is not 'All' else it should not JOIN and continue further. I have already tried by using "OR" (to short-circuit) and "IN" (to apply filter) but the performance slows down if you have too many items in IN clause. 
Please help me and do tell me if I was wrong anywhere in my approach.

**Sample Data:**

I should get the INNER JOIN result only when variable <> 'all'
[image]

When variable = 'All', I should get table A i.e.

[image]

**Note:** I have simplified this query hence it appears that simple if statement can do. In actual I have 53 parameters that I need to check and run JOINS. Plus result set of one query must be joined with another i.e. I have several other JOIN conditions preceding this :)

Comment: not sure what you trying to do, but from "TABLE SCAN" value I Can say your table doesn't have indexes and hence the join might be slow. I have join million records in either way and it never slows for me and what you trying to do in "on" will actually result in cartesian product of tables.

Comment: @SumitGupta What I m trying to do is "short circuit". If variable is 'All' the Cartesian Product should not even happen, the join must be ignored.

Comment: If you had provided us with an example of sample data and expected output it would be much easier to understand what you want.

Comment: I have included sample data. This is just for trial. Actual project data is bigger and tables are complicated.

Comment: as I understand you are messing up in your need and database structure. if you get that variable without and other condition it will give null values for table b if condition is false, and it give cartesian product if condition is true and then filter on your where condition. The better create a procedure and put 2 query with condition on variable. So one queyr will be with join and other is without join.

Comment: As I understand you are asking me to write a dynamic sql? Please correct me if I m wrong. I have also corrected the question. Can you please tell me if my approach was right? Was Join completely wiped out when variable was 'All'

Comment: you can say dynamic [though it is not dynamic], if you don't want join then simply don't write join. So in your store procedure, just put if (@a <> 'All') then execute different query and else different. your above query does enjoy in both case. unfortunately. :).

Comment: So, thing is I have simplified this query hence it appears that simple if statement can do. In actual I have 53 parameters that I need to check and run JOINS. Plus result set of one query must be joined with another i.e. I have several other JOIN conditions preceding this :)

Comment: I would say that this is expected behavior. The optimizer has to write (and store) a plan that will work regardless of the value of @a. Which is frustrates your goal here, but makes sure that the CPU isn't stuck always doing query optimization.

Comment: The query plan is not going to actually evaluate the condition ON @a <> 'All'.  It just creates a plan for the query to evaluate the conditions.  That query plan does NOT short circuit the join.  It clearly states Nested Loops (left outer join).

Comment: @Blam thanks for commenting. Does that mean that my query short circuits the INNER JOIN ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
SELECT  A.*
FROM    [dbo].[your_table] A
WHERE   EXISTS  (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    [dbo].[your_table_2] B
            WHERE   A.City_Code = B.City_Code
        )
OR  @a = 'All'
```

Comment: This won't give me an INNER JOIN result if I have @a <> 'All' right?

Comment: If @a <> 'All', then it will ensure that only results from table A is returned that exists in table B, which is the same as an INNER JOIN.

Comment: What if table_1 and table_2 both have duplicate data? INNER JOIN will give me a result with all the combinations of City_Code but this will not. I tried your query on my data set and gives me different result than what I get from an INNER JOIN. Do you want me to describe the table schema and data as well in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try case statement? The CASE or DECODE is usually like an IF-ELSE statement in the SQL.

Comment: So, thing is I have simplified this query hence it appears that simple IF/ CASE statement can do. In actual I have 53 parameters that I need to check and run JOINS. Plus result set of one query must be joined with another i.e. I have several other JOIN conditions preceding this :)

Comment: Yes, so what i wanted to say is that, LEFT JOIN ON  CASE STATEMENT, and inside that, check for INNER JOIN, if INNER JOIN returns the value, means, that's true TRUE, hence, LEFT JOIN condition must be checked, else LEFT JOIN must fail. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Or you can do like LEFT JOIN ON WHERE EXISTS, and then INNER JOIN, if no value is present here, means, EXISTS condition is a failure. I am sorry for the syntaxes.